# ¿Como puedo inicializar un puntero a un objeto en c++?

Tags: c++, poo

Quisiera saber como puedo inicializar ese puntero a un objeto de otra clase y como inicializarlo si  fuera un objeto de otra clase como atributo.

```
class Pedido {
public:
    Pedido();
    Pedido(char*, float,int);
    ~Pedido(){}
private:
    Cliente* Cliente;
    char NombrePedido[50];
    float costoPedido;
    int Cantidad;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero una recomendación:

- Es preferible utilizar nombres que inicien con minúsculas para los datos miembro. Puedes usar el `camelCase` o `snake_case` para los nombres de variables.  En tu caso, sería `Cliente* cliente`.

Existen un par de maneras de establecer un miembro, en este caso, `cliente` es un dato miembro y puedes inicializarlo en el constructor o mediante un establecedor (*setter*), como comenta Franco Dreher.

Si lo inicializas en un constructor, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera, asumiendo que `cliente` es un dato miembro de tipo `Cliente*`.

`Pedido::Pedido(Cliente* cliente, .../*otros parámetros/*)
       :cliente(cliente)
       ,/*inicialización de otros datos miembro*/ {}`

Observa que *cliente* tiene una duración/tiempo de vida útil y en algún momento debe ser eliminado mediante una llamada a *delete*. Eso es material para otro día.

Puedes encontrar más información en la referencia de C++ en español:
[Inicialización de miembros](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Inicializaci%C3%B3n%20de%20miembros)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes instanciar un cliente en la función main y cuando instancias un objeto de pedido setear el cliente que hizo el pedido.

Necesitas crear los getter y los setter en el archivo Pedido.cpp si es que no los has creado:

```
void Pedido::setPedido(Cliente* cliente){
    this->Cliente = cliente;
}
```